# How to update table using sequence in variable for each record one by one php

Tags: php, mysql

I have all records in sequence from 1 onwards for each record displayed but wish to update each one with that sequence in a field within the table.

Any help?

```html
if(isset($_POST['setorder']))
{ 
 $i = 1;
 //$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));
 $routesql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE status = 1");
 while ($routerows = $routesql->fetch_array())
 {
 $rname = $routerows['routename'];
 $routejobs = $mysqli->query("select tracking.*, district.* from tracking left join district on tracking.street = district.street
 where tracking.date = '$today' AND tracking.status = 2 and route = '$rname' order by district.sortorder asc");
 while ($routejrows = $routejobs->fetch_array())
 {
 echo $i.' - '.$routejrows['joborder'].' - '.$routejrows['addressto'];
 echo '<br/>';
 $i++;
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: So you want to update each row with the corresponding value of $i, is that right? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes and tried various things no luck mostly it allocates the same value to each record no in sequence

Comment: what did you do, exactly? I'd expect a simple `UPDATE` sql query within that `while` loop, with `$i` passed in as a parameter, should do the job. It depends a bit which field in which table exactly you're trying to update. Some sample data and expected result would make this a lot clearer (since we don't know your data structure at all)

Comment: Am trying to update the tracking table with associated job order field with $i variable

Comment: so `UPDATE tracking SET somefield = ? WHERE ...` should be the general idea. And `$i` is used as the parameter for `?`. The WHERE clause I guess should include something from $routejrows which uniquely identifies the row in the tracking table. Did you try something like that? As I said, it's hard to make specific suggestions when we don't know what you tried already and we can't see the precise structure or data from the tables. If I'm not making sense, then consider updating your question with relevant info so we can make better suggestions. Thanks.